# Merging two git repositories, or using fast-import twice

Tags: git, performance, import, merge

I'm currently running a script, which is importing data from IMS Integrity VCS into a Git Repo using git's fast import backend. However, after 4000 commits, the serverside memory of IMS breaks. I'm not sure if I'm able to clear its cache manually, so I wanted to ask if there is a way to run git's fast import twice on the same repo, or merge two repos into one with a common history. Thanks in advance.